# Prevent form from refreshing the page

Tags: javascript

Hey I am trying to use a form to submit data via JavaScript but it keeps refreshing the page when I don't want it to.

My form is like this:

```
<form name="myForm" method="post">

<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add Resource" onclick="insert(); return false;"/>

</form>
```

My JS function has:

```
function insert(e){
e.preventDefault();
    var name = document.myForm.name;
    console.log(name);    
}
```

I was told prevent default is how you stop the default action of the form but it still happens for me. How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing in `e` though.  Instead, it would be better to bind to the form with JavaScript rather than using an attribute:

```
document.querySelector('[name=myForm]').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

You could also bind to the `click` event of the submit input

Comment: So how come onclick in html doesn't parse `e` but an event listener does by default? Aren't they the same thing =/

Comment: @Dave you don't even send `e` in .. you call `insert()` with no arguments.  That is by far not the preferred method, (using `onclick` I mean) anyway.

Comment: This method is ie8+, which is reasonable. However, ie8 will not properly send `e`, so you may need to check `if( typeof(e) == "undefined" ) e = event;`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I thought event was passed automatically with event listeners...when they call the desired function you chose.

Comment: @TravisJ indeed, and IE8- does not even support `addEventListener` (I think), it needs `attachEvent`, but I'm hoping I can help kill the use of those browser somehow...

Comment: @Dave it is -- you can see in my `addEventListener` callback that I don't have to do anything special to get `e` as it's passed in as a parameter.  What you have would be equivalent to something like `addEventListener('click', function (e) { insert(); })` -- `e` does not get used even though it might be passed.

Comment: So an onclick in html like onclick="" does not count as an eventListener in the same way ? Even though they do the same thing =/

Comment: @Dave maybe they do because of the browser's underlying capability, but the `on` attributes do not use the standard event listener pattern (you can't bind and unbind multiple events with it) and separating JS and HTML is always a big plus in my very humble opinion